# Sony HiFi STK 403-130 Question

Tags: amplifier

I am going to separately use sony HiFi stk 403-130 amp circuit.

In the below image, I marked numbers in RED

1 - What voltage 5/9/12 DC/AC should I input to run number 3 Relay.

2 - What voltage 5/9/12 DC/AC should I input to mute sound.

[image]

Comment: It looks to me as though the Mute function is activated by pulling Pin-11 to ground, while simply leaving it open will un-mute (or maybe the other way around). You don't need to apply a voltage to that pin to control it - just ground or open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *1 - What voltage 5/9/12 DC/AC should I input to run number 3 Relay.*

If reusing the same relay then either measure what voltage activates the coil or figure out the part number and find the data sheet. If a brand new relay....

Firstly, choose an appropriate relay that has a coil operating voltage to suit your needs and has a limit of much less than 50 volts (that's the rating of Q488, the [2SC2785 transistor](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf/71179/NEC/2SC2785/1) used in the design). You do need to check on contact wetting current and, if in doubt, choose a sealed relay that guarantees operation down to a few tens of microamps of current.

But you also need to choose a relay that can operate with several amps of current passing through the contacts and, choose one that has low degradation on those contacts over time. It's not easy to figure out and certainly, without a definitive specification of the amplifier's output drive capabilities, it's something you'll have to research.

> *2 - What voltage 5/9/12 DC/AC should I input to mute sound.*

The answer above is the same.

Comment: I just removed Q489 transistor and add a jumper for solving the mute option, now it's working fine.

Comment: BTW thanks for explaining in detail :)